# Cardinal of set goes to infinity a.s.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, almost-everywhere

Supposem $X1,X2,...$ are i.i.d. and $X1$ takes each value $j$ with probability $p_j$. Let $D_n$ be the number of distinct values $j$ among $X1,X2,...X_n$, that is, $D_n=|{X1,X2,...,X_n}|

(i) Show that $D \rightarrow \infty$ a.s.

(ii) show that $ED_n/n \rightarrow 0$.

My solution: Let Define the events $A_j=\{j \in D_n \ \text{for some} n\}$.  So, $P(A_j^c)=P\{j \notin D_n \ \text{for all} \ n \}=lim (1-p_j)^n=0$. Hence, $P(A_j)=1$.

We have

$P(D_n \rightarrow \infty)=P(A_j \ \text{i.o.})=P(limsup A_j)\geq limsup P(A_j)=1$

I am not sure my solution is correct.

For (ii), I wanted to calculate the expectation but it seems to be hard to calculate it.

Comment: For (i), some hypothesis is missing, for example that the set of possible values $j$ is infinite. For (ii), one can use the explicit formula $$E(D_n)=\sum_j(1-P(j\notin\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}))=\sum_j(1-(1-p_i)^n)$$ and deduce that $$E(D_{n+1}-D_n)=\sum_jp_i(1-p_i)^n$$ where the RHS goes to zero by dominated convergence, which implies (ii).

Comment: I couldn't understand the last line.

Comment: Which last line?

Comment: Why RHS goes to zero and why it implies $ED_n/n$ goes to zero.

Comment: You know, after a while, you might want to try to add something of your own to the proof, not only ask for it bit by bit... Sure you cannot show, **using the explicit indication I gave**, that $$\sum_jp_j(1-p_j)^n\to0\ ?$$ Sure you cannot show that $E(D_{n+1}-D_n)\to0$ implies $E(D_n)/n\to0$? Ad lib.

Comment: I think we can use cesaro mean lemma for showing that $E(D_n)/n \rightarrow 0$. But I couldn't show $\sum_{j} p_j(1-p_j)^n \rightarrow 0 $.