# Inequality for probability distribution

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose that $\sum_{I=1}^{\infty}p_i=1$ and $p_i\geq 0$. Show that $\sum_{i}p_i(1-p_i)^n$ goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

My idea: I tried to use the inequality $(1-p_i)^n\geq 1-np_i$ but I think we need to use an inequality in opposite side.

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Or Dominated convergence theorem

Comment: Can you please post full solutions? You will have an upvote from me for sure.  I've encountered MCT and DCT only in the context of measure theory and sums are confusing me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @asdf If you are familiar with DCT, you should be able to apply it here. Summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is just integration, where the measure space is $\mathbb N_+$ with counting measure, and the function begin integrated is $n\mapsto a_n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh, I see, so I should think of sums as counting measure? That's neat, thanks a lot! (+1) for the comment!

Comment: @asdf Sure thing! There is one caveat; technically, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^M a_n$, and this limit may exist even though $a_n$ is not "Lebesgue integrable." For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/n$ exists in the calculus sense by the alternating series test, but not in the Lebesgue sense, since it is of the form $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: Auto-duplicate. You already have been given the argument to solve the question. Do not do that.

Comment: @Did  It wasn't me who asked the question? I have nothing to do with OP and was trying to solve it on my own

Comment: @asdf My comment was addressed to the OP (S_Alex), as you can deduce from the fact that it does not start with your username. Are you them?

Comment: @Did My comment wasn't intended to be mean. Got confused by the "You already have been given the argument to solve the question." bit since the argument in the post doesn't work.

Comment: @asdf The OP already posted this, on another page, there they were given specific indications to solve the question, which they chose to ignore, then they probably deleted their post before reposting the present duplicate.

Comment: @Did: was that on another site? I don't see a duplicate post on MSE by this author (deleted or not).

Comment: @Did: nvm, I see the comments in which the question was addressed.

Comment: However, the [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931359/cardinal-of-set-goes-to-infinity-a-s#comment6059222_2931359) indicates the OP is still confused. If they need further explanation, a new question seems acceptable. However, they should have mentioned where they were confused about the application of Dominated Convergence.

Comment: Now we know the present question should be closed as a deliberate duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931359).

Answer (score 1):

What you should notice is that each term converges to zero: $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_i(1-p_i)^n = 0$. So the question is, how to harness this observation to produce the same conclusion for the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i(1-p_i)^n$. A natural idea will be to interchange the order of limit and summation. However, we also know that this is not always possible, so you will end up seeking a mathematical result that ensures this.

As many users pointed out, either [*monotone convergence theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series) or [*dominated convergence theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) fits in your situation. Although not mentioned in comments, even [*Weierstrass $M$-test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) can be used to justify this. And the common reason why all these fancy techniques are available is that we have a summable dominating sequence $\{p_i\}$ for $\{p_i(1-p_i)^n\}$.

As a final blow, let me provide a low-tech solution (which of course critically rely on the above observation) : Fix $N$ and take limsup as $n\to\infty$ to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i (1-p_i)^n \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i (1-p_i)^n \right) + \left( \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_i \right). $$

Then using the [subadditivity of limsup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties), we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i (1-p_i)^n \leq \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_i. $$

Since the limsup in the left is a fixed number which is independent of $N$, we can let $N\to\infty$ to both sided to obtain $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i (1-p_i)^n \leq 0$. Since the complementary inequality for liminf is trivial, it follows that the sum converges to $0$ a $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Been a while, but I think this does it.

Let a = $\sum_{i}p_i(1-p_i)^n$ and b=$\sum_{i}(1-p_i)^n$.

and c= $\sum_{i}(1-p_i)$^(n+1).

b-a=c, so b=a+c.

$0<p_i$<1, so $p_i^k$<$p_i^m$ if k>m. We also have $p_i(1-p_i)^n$<$(1-p_i)^n$ since (1-$p_i$ ) is also positive.

Note c and b have the same necessarily finite limit, so we avoid indeterminate terms. a being equal to b-c, with c and b being finite and determinate, lim a = lim (b-c)=0.

Comment: is there a mistake int he proof? Should I add more detail?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see that your solution is flawed because $b$ and $c$ are *necessarily* infinite. Just notice that $\lim_{i\to\infty} (1-p_i)^n = 1$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty} (1-p_i)^{n+1} = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. I was thinking since the $p_i$ are all positive and add up to one, then   $ 1-p_i$  is also less than 1 and $(1-p_i)^n$ goes to 0. I think I haven't done that part due justice though.

Comment: I'm thinking something can be done by considering two cases, if $p_i<1/2$ and $p_i>1/2$.

Comment: $1-p_i$ need not be less than one, and even it is less than one, the issue of divergence persists. You are not taking summation over $n$, but rather over $i$. And for each summation, $n$ is fixed. It will be easier to see this with a concrete example: If $n = 2018$ and $p_i = 2^{-i}$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-p_i)^n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^i}\right)^{2018}. $$ Notice that the general term even does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Don't these combined imply $p_i <1$? If we assume $1-p_i>1$, then we must have $-p_i>0$ and so $p_i<0$ contradicting one of the givens, right?

$\sum_{I=1}^{\infty}p_i=1$ and $p_i\geq 0$

Comment: One may have $p_i = 0$ for some $i$ and thus $1-p_i = 1$. For instance, let $p$ be the p.m.f. of a binomial distribution. Then $p_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$. But as I said, this is not a problem in your answer. The real issue is that $(1-p_i)^n \to 1$ as $i\to\infty$.

Comment: You're right, i missed the equal bar. Thanks!

Comment: If we have $p_i=0$ for some $i$, that means it won't contribute to $p_i(1-p_i)^n$, right? If we have for some $i$ that $p_i=1$, then that the sum of all $p_i$ must equal $1$ suggests all the other $p_i$ are 0, right? 

I suspect without loss of generality we can assume if any $p_i$ is $0$ we can ignore it, and that if any $p_i$ is 1, then the rest are zero. If any $p_i$ is between 0 and 1, then we cannot have any other $p_i$ be equal to 1 since that would raise the total above the stipulated threshold. I think this could help break the analysis into 3 different cases.